# Get the time when the file was last used

Tags: java, matlab, fileinfo

I would like to run MATLAB (Java would also be good, but for now I need MATLAB) script which can retrieve the time when the file was last used. I have already set in command prompt the availability of this information (it is visible in file properties window). Now i want to automatically get this information.
Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is access the information when a file was last *changed*. Other than that, I believe Matlab has no inbuilt functionality for getting additional information saved in file properties.

```
file = dir(fullpathtofile);
file.date
```